# Profile Manager with Combobox and TIniFile

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm currently trying to create a "Profile Manager" using a TIniFile to store the data, and displaying the data in various components on a form (editboxes and such).

On the form, i've got a Combobox. This serves as a way of displaying the "Profile Name" as set by the user.

The data is being stored in the format of 1 profile per inifile section. Each section contains the configuration data for 1 profile including the Profile Name. The profile name key is the same across each section. This is the sort of layout i've currently got in the inifile (as an example);

```
[0]
PROFILE_NAME=Profile 1A
PROFILE_DATA=Profile Data 1A
PROFILE_PASS=Profile Password 1
PROFILE_USER=Profile Username 1
[1]
PROFILE_NAME=Profile 1B
PROFILE_DATA=Profile Data 1B
PROFILE_PASS=Profile Password 1B
PROFILE_USER=Profile Username 1B
```

What i want to do is load a list of all values with the key "PROFILE_NAME" into a combobox regardless of what section they're located in. The section names themselves are references to the itemindex in the combobox when that data was added.

From there, i can handle loading the other data into it's relevant fields, but i'm having a problem figuring out how to load the "PROFILE_NAME" values into the combobox. Any ideas?

For those familiar with the Voice Communication program "Ventrilo", it features something similar to what i'm trying to achieve with it's "Server and User Manager". It's inifile layout is very similar, and the only difference i can find is that it has a "USER_COUNT" value referencing how many users have been added. Each user has servers assigned to them, rather than the servers being accessible by every user.

Is it possible for me to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `TIniFile.ReadSections` to get a list of all the section names, and then you can loop through them and read the individual `PROFILE_NAME` from each of those sections. (I prefer `TMemIniFile`, as `TIniFile` is based on the WinAPI functions directly and has issues sometimes on network drives when trying to update with new values. `TMemIniFile` also works cross-platform when you get to `XE2`.)

I'm creating the `TMemIniFile` and `TStringList` and freeing them, but if you're using them repeatedly you'll probably want to create them in your form's `OnCreate` and free them in `FormClose` instead; that way you'll have a list of the section names to match back to the items in the `ComboBox` when you want to access the rest of the items in the `OnClick` event to populate the rest of the form.

```
var
  Sections: TStringList;
  Ini: TMemIniFile;
  s: string;
begin
  Sections := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Ini := TMemIniFile.Create('YourIniFile.ini');
    try
      Ini.ReadSections(Sections);
      for s in Sections do
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(Ini.ReadString(s, `PROFILE_NAME`, `Empty`);
    finally
      Ini.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Sections.Free;
  end;
end;
```

To make it easier to tie back to the items in the `ComboBox`, declare a new integer variable (`i` in my snippet below), and change the `for` loop to this (make sure you don't sort the `Sections` - let the `ComboBox` handle the sorting!):

```
for i := 0 to Sections.Count - 1 do
begin
  s := Ini.ReadString(Sections[i], 'PROFILE_NAME', 'Empty');
  ComboBox1.Items.AddObject(s, TObject(i));
end;
```

To get the section name again when the user clicks a combobox item:

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  SectionName: string;
begin
  // Get the Sections item index we stored above
  i := Integer(ComboBox1.Items.Objects[ComboBox1.ItemIndex]));

  // Get the associated Sections section name
  SectionName := Sections[i]; 

  // Use the retrieved section name to get the rest of the values
  ProfileNameEdit.Text := Ini.ReadString(SectionName, 'PROFILE_NAME', '');
  ProfileDataEdit.Text := Ini.ReadString(SectionName, 'PROFILE_DATA', ''); // etc
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for that Ken! The code _almost_ works perfectly, and it's loading the details perfectly! It's merely down to me changing a small part of my other code so it uses `PROFILE_NAME` as the section name. However, for the purpose of other people who stumble upon this in future, is it possible that it displays `PROFILE_NAME` as the name of the item in the combobox (using the `replacement for loop that uses an integer`)? _I've still given this the accept since the code itself works without issue and the explanation is excellent!_

Comment: Oops! My mistake. Fixed the code to do just that (which is what I first intended it to do).